# secret_key_base Error in Production Mode Ruby on Rails using HostGator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, production, secret-key

Error that I get :

```
App 1077 stderr: [ 2017-03-18 15:56:25.9166 1116/0x007f13c5aa39c8(Worker 1) utils.rb:87 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 1116, thread 0x007f13c5aa39c8(Worker 1)):
```

I have this code in my `secrets.yml` :

```
development:
  secret_key_base: f8eed700430c3828f1f3c84627b29de146e1c73bae55b31142b9339e95ca4962cf0922b3be80d0733fb0f03f35d00c7ea21dca205ffd0bdf1ae48cf4f874af86

test:
  secret_key_base: 452aa27249ce5eae3290bae7dec500baa0aa0a4bb963a9846aed4e67796d13abcc84d51369ca9f09e002b78f17a42e08e3f590dbb4bc53e197497a68e470eaf8

'# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
'# instead read values from the environment.

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: take a look this line `'# Do not keep production secrets in the repository, '# instead read values from the environment.` you should put a secret key to environment file

Comment: How do I do that? Isn't the last line doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by going to /environments/production.rb and putting in `config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]`